# closed popup once state changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

this 'style' is currently stored in Popup.js
now i move this style to dedicated css file.
but the problem is css can not detect showPopup properties.
Any way how can I solve this?

```
    const style = {
    display: showPopup ? "block" : "none",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    width: "300px",
    height: "200px",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    border: "1px solid #ccc",
    padding: "20px",
    zIndex: "1000"
    };
```

Full code in Popup.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import classes from './Popup.css';

const Popup = () => {
    // Create a state variable to control the visibility of the popup
    const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

    // Use useEffect to show the popup when the component mounts
    useEffect(() => {
        setShowPopup(true);
        }, []);

    //Define some styles for the popup element
    const style = {
    display: showPopup ? "block" : "none",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    width: "300px",
    height: "200px",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    border: "1px solid #ccc",
    padding: "20px",
    zIndex: "1000"
    };

    return (
        <div>     
        <div className={classes.Popup}>
        <h1>Warning</h1>   
        <button onClick={() => setShowPopup(false)}>Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        );
}
 
export default Popup;
```

popup will closed when user click button

Comment: You are just moving it to css file as a js constant. that is not how it works ! you need to define class name in css and  normal css value there and in CSS syntax not js. and use class name in div as string  just import css anywhere.